# How to specify a condition when equating expressions

Tags: equations

I do not know how this concept is called in mathematics, but when you are working on an expression, you may operate step by step, saying: "this equals this, and equals this, and equals this..."

But sometimes, you need to specify "this equals this, only if x is not zero", for example when operating and putting **x** into a denominator.

When drawing on a paper you just write around the equal symbol a note and say: "from now on, x cannot be zero", but I don't know how to express this on a TeX version of a mathematical process representation.

I tried it like this, but it doesn't seem very accurate to me:

[image: Example]

What is your suggestion or the standard way of achieving this, if any? Thank you.

**Edit**:

This is the LaTeX code of the attached image example.

```
\begin{aligned}L\left[ f\left( t\right) \right] =\int ^{\infty }_{0}e^{-st}\cdot f\left( t\right) dt=\lim _{b\rightarrow \infty }\int ^{b}_{0}e^{-st}.f\left( t\right) dt=\lim _{b\rightarrow \infty }\left[ \int ^{3}_{0}e^{-st}\cdot 0\cdot dt+\int ^{b}_{3}e^{-st}\cdot 1\cdot dt\right] =\\
=\lim _{b\rightarrow \infty }\left[ 0+\int ^{b}_{3}e^{-st}\cdot 1\cdot dt\right] =\lim _{b\rightarrow \infty }\left[ \dfrac {e^{-st}}{-s}\right] ^{b}_{3}=\left[ \forall s\neq 0\right] =\end{aligned}
```

Comment: BTW, I'm pretty sure we need `s > 0`, otherwise the integral doesn't converge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Conditionals in mathematics are often expressed using a `{ <expr> | <cond> }` format, read as `<expr> given <cond>`. Perhaps consider that here:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\newcommand{\Laplace}{\mathcal{L}\laplace}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\laplace}{[}{]}
\newcommand{\dt}{\,\mathrm{d}t}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \Laplace[\big]{f(t)} 
    &= \int_0^\infty e^{-st} \cdot f(t) \dt \\
    &= \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^b e^{-st} \cdot f(t) \dt \\
    &= \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \biggl[ \int_0^3 e^{-st} \cdot 0 \dt + \int_3^b e^{-st} \cdot 1 \dt \biggr] \\
    &= \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \biggl[ 0 + \int_3^b e^{-st} \cdot 1 \dt \biggr] \\
    &= \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \biggl[ \dfrac {e^{-st}}{-s} \biggm\vert s \neq 0 \biggr]_3^b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

or just include it as a description:

[image]

```
\begin{align*}
  % ...
    &= \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty} \biggl[ \dfrac {e^{-st}}{-s} \biggr]_3^b \qquad \text{(where $s \neq 0$)}
\end{align*}
```